# Is 'si dispiace' ever an acceptable form of the verb dispiacere?

Tags: verbs

Reading the following excerpt for a book entitled *L'arte di annacarsi*, I noticed the use of 'si dispiace':

> I siciliani toccano. Ti toccano un braccio mentre cercano di capire di cosa hai bisogno e anche di cosa non sai ancora di avere bisogno. La sensazione di essere toccati può rivelarsi sgradevole, per il viaggiatore, ma anche lui a poco a poco si abitua, e alla fine qualcuno persino ***si dispiace*** quando poi nessuno lo tocca più.

Dispiacere (as well as piacere, mancare, bastare, occorrere) behave differently from other verbs. They are formed with the structure, ***indirect object + verb + subject***, where the subject is the thing that is (dis)liked (missed, sufficient, necessary) and the indirect object is the one doing the action.

Given that, why is the verb in the above context not ***gli dispiace*** or does *dispiacere* break the usual rules when used in a reflexive sense?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this context, "si dispiace" is correct; "gli dispiace" would be wrong.

Here you have an example of the meaning marked with **3.** by the [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dispiacere2/).

The subject is "qualcuno", the verb is reflexive (not impersonal) and is "dispiacersi", so it follows the same pattern as, for example:

> **Qualcuno si stupisce se ...**
>
> **Qualcuno si arrabbia se ...**

so:

> **Qualcuno si dispiace se ...**

An example with another person to make the distinction clearer:

> **Mi stupisco della tua sconfitta**   (reflexive, "io" is the implicit subject, "mi" is the direct object)
>
> **Mi stupisce la tua sconfitta**   (here "mi" means "a me", "la tua sconfitta" is the subject)

Similar example with "dispiacere":

> **Mi dispiaccio della tua sconfitta**  (reflexive, "mi" is the direct object)
>
> **Mi dispiace [la tua sconfitta|che tu sia stato sconfitto]**   (here "mi" means "a me", "la tua sconfitta" etc. is the subject)

So in the sentence you cite the difference could be made explicit, for example, as follows:

> **e alla fine qualcuno persino si dispiace quando ...**  (reflexive, "qualcuno" is the subject)
>
> **e alla fine *a* qualcuno persino dispiace quando ...**  ("[a] qualcuno" is an indirect object)